# JSDoc for multi level constructor functions for WebStorm IntelliSense

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc, commonjs, node-modules

(All of the following files are in this [GitHub](https://github.com/ManuelRauber/jsdoc-sample) repo, too)

I'm currently developing a node module which will have the following structure:

```
- some-module
  - foo.js
  - objects.js
  - index.js
```

**foo.js** contains a constructor function which will be exported via `module.exports = ConstructorFunction`:

```
'use strict';

function Foo(someVar) {
    this.bar = function () {
        return someVar;
    };
}

Foo.prototype.fooBar = function () {
    return 'FooBar';
};


Object.defineProperty(Foo.prototype, 'someProp', { value: 'Hello World!' });

module.exports = Foo;
```

Imagine that within one package there a lot of files like foo.js, since this is auto generated code (> 50 files).

**objects.js** requires all files like foo.js and exports them within an object like so:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    Foo: require('./foo')
};
```

(Same here: If there are > 50 files, objects.js would contain 50 definitions as seen above)

**index.js** only exports the required objects.js file: `module.exports = require('./objects');`

What a now want is the following usage:

```
'use strict';

var someModule = require('./some-module');

// How to get IntelliSense for constructor function and x?
// Without (!) adding /** @type {Foo} */ here!
var x = new someModule.Foo('Hello!');

console.log(x.someProp);
console.log(x.fooBar());
console.log(x.bar());
```

Is there a possibility to get WebStorm IntelliSense for `new someModule.Foo()` and the resulting instance `x`? Ideally it would be possible without adding a type annotation for `x` (with it, it would work like a charm).

I dismissed all jsdoc in this sample to have a fresh start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did ever figure this out?

Comment: @IanBytchek nope. Even with the new version of WebStorm, which has a much better IntelliSense, still not working. :(

Comment: I've figured out it's time to give TypeScript a go. Been pretty awesome so far.